# TTS inside button wont read multiple strings

Tags: android, string, button, timer, text-to-speech

I am writing my first android application and I have a few problems with one activity. I am trying to add tts and timers which will be activated on a button push.  I have a few questions on this and will be splitting up my questions into separate threads  :).  Let me start with the tts issues first.

When I added the tts function onInit it works fine.  when I put this is as Random random it read the strings as one long sentence, but it read it.  But when I added the tts call to a button, and I need to have 2 strings read,......

```
   Button Start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
           // Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),     MainActivity.class); //put timer start here
          //  startActivity(myIntent);

            tts.speak(voice[2], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);           //falls through to 4 and timer does not start.
            tts.speak("... ",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            tts.speak(voice[0], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    Timer1.start();
            //pause here 5 seconds
                    //Timer2.start();
            //pause here 5 minutes
                // Timer3.start();
            //continue code from here
            // startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

.......I had to take out the Intent or it crashes the project.  When I do this it falls through and only reads the last string.  And when I add the timer calls, which are probably written wrong, it crashes the project. I think I have the timer functions written correctly but that's the next thread. I know I have this written wrong.  But I can find nothing anywhere with an example of how this is done.

So what I need help with: 
1. getting the button to read several strings from an array with pauses
2. getting the function calls written correctly to activate the timers

I have one basic java programming class I have taken and this is my first android app.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tts=new TextToSpeech(myCode.this,new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener(){
             public void onInit(int status){
                 if (status!= TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                     tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                     tts.speak(voice[2], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

Comment: Im sorry.  It would not let me add this in the post

Comment: Awesome!!!!!! I will try this when I get home from work.   I think this will be exactly what I need.  Thank you so much.  This is so exciting.

Comment: Works Perfectly!!!!!!!!

Comment: I added that as an answer, so that you can accept it and remove it from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Use **QUEUE_ADD** instead of **QUEUE_FLUSH**.